# Confused about OnCommand and CommandName attribute in asp button control

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEditAdd" Text="Edit" 
CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Visible="false" runat="server" OnCommand="btnEditAdd_Click"/>
```

How come the above control's got both OnCommand and CommandName attribute? When that button is clicked what method is called ? I don't why I am confused.

I mean the repeater's ItemCommand event is fired or btnEditAdd_Click is called??

I thot they both serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, ItemCommand is a property which helps to identify whether a separate event handler is to be called or the items own event handler is to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this yourself by placing breakpoints on both the `btnEditAdd_Click` event and repater's ItemCommand.  If both breakpoints are hit then both events are being called.

Answer (score 0):

The `CommandName` property is just a string identifier.

The `btnEditAdd_Click` method will be called, and its `e` parameter will contain the `CommandName`.

The repeater's `ItemCommand` event will also be fired.